# Как добраться до кода?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, jsoup

Работаю над мобильным приложением для сайта. 
Сайт не мой, поэтому его приходится парсить.
 Дело в том, что при нажатии кнопки:

```
<div class="icePnlGrp nodeContent" id="mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id143"><a class="iceCmdLnk" href="javascript:;" id="mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id144" onblur="setFocus(&#39;&#39;);" onclick="var form=formOf(this);form[&#39;mainform:_idcl&#39;].value=&#39;mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id144&#39;;return iceSubmitPartial(form,this,event);" onfocus="setFocus(this.id);"><span class="iceOutTxt" id="mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id145" title="Выбрать &quot;Мои задачи (0)&quot;">Мои задачи (0)</span></a></div></div>
```

открывается табличка, которая в исходном коде отсутствует
, однако в консоли разработчика Chrome все элементы как на ладони:

Парсю JSOUP поэтому выдираю html страницу загруженного сайта, в котором этих элементов нет. Подскажите как до них добраться?

При проверке запросов при нажатии кнопки есть 1 запрос
POST https://URL/home/block/send-receive-updates
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Request Headers
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  JSESSIONID=A82CB6C0C81AF9272BD72961E1F3085B.singlenode;
ice.sessions=feBsztdrC04js2dgk0eGSw#1 TCfkqn0OYY6MKJ-cF4gZvQ#1
Origin  https://URL
Referer https://URL/home/bpms/modes/tasks/taskList.seam
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id E167B841-7F28-42E2-A1BB-BB7CB4850E48
Response Headers
Cache-Control   no-cache
Cache-Control   no-store
Cache-Control   must-revalidate
Connection  close
Content-Length  50707
Content-Type    text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date    Thu, 24 Dec 2015 05:22:54 GMT
Expires 0
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By    Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.3.0.GA_CP09 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_4_3_0_GA_CP09 date=201011090309)/JBossWeb-2.0
X-Powered-By    ICEfacesEE

Form Data
ice.submit.partial:true
ice.event.target:mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id145
ice.event.captured:mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id144
ice.event.type:onclick
ice.event.alt:false
ice.event.ctrl:false
ice.event.shift:false
ice.event.meta:false
ice.event.x:99
ice.event.y:114
ice.event.left:false
ice.event.right:false
mainform:iceDND:
mainform:_idcl:mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id144
mainform:procSearch:
mainform:j_id150ClickedNodeName:
mainform:j_id150Expanded:
mainform:_idmainform:groupingColumnsPositionedcolOrder:
mainform:_idmainform:sortingColumnsPositionedcolOrder:
mainform:j_id137ClickedNodeName:
mainform:j_id137Expanded:
mainform:mainform:queryTree_idtn:
mainform:mainform:queryTree_idta:
javax.faces.RenderKitId:ICEfacesRenderKit
javax.faces.ViewState:5
icefacesCssUpdates:
mainform:
ice.session:TCfkqn0OYY6MKJ-cF4gZvQ
ice.view:5
ice.focus:mainform:queryTree:n-0:j_id144
rand:0.1277136062271893

```
<updates><update address="j_id107dynamic-code" tag="script"><attribute name="id"><![CDATA[j_id107dynamic-code]]></attribute><attribute name="type"><![CDATA[text/javascript]]></attribute><content><![CDATA[ if (this.addEventListener) { this.addEventListener('keydown', processKeyDown2193991, false); } else {
 document.attachEvent('onkeydown', function () {processKeyDown2193991(event); });  } 
  function processKeyDown2193991(event) { 
  return;} 
]]></content></update><update address="mainform:j_id619-2-0" tag="td"><attribute name="class"><![CDATA[icePnlGrdCol1]]></attribute><attribute name="id"><![CDATA[mainform:j_id619-2-0]]></attribute><content><![CDATA[<table class="icePnlGrd dataListPaginatorClass" id="mainform:j_id1248"><tbody><tr class="icePnlGrdRow1 dataListPaginatorClassRow1"><td class="icePnlGrdCol1 dataListPaginatorClassCol1" id="mainform:j_id1248-0-0"><span id="mainform:j_id1249" onclick="var form=formOf(this);form[&#39;mainform:_idcl&#39;].value=&#39;mainform:j_id1249&#39;;return iceSubmit(form,this,event);"><img alt="" class="iceGphImg" id="mainform:j_id1250" src="https://83.239.45.27:8080/AWCResources/~avs2.39.5.4613~ave/img/arrow-first.gif" style="opacity: 0.5;" /></span></td><td class="icePnlGrdCol2 dataListPaginatorClassCol2" id="mainform:j_id1248-0-1"><span id="mainform:j_id1251" onclick="var form=formOf(this);form[&#39;mainform:_idcl&#39;].value=&#39;mainform:j_id1251&#39;;return iceSubmit(form,this,event);"><img alt="" class="iceGphImg" id="mainform:j_id1252" src="https://URL/AWCResources/~avs2.39.5.4613~ave/img/arrow-previous.gif" style="opacity: 0.5;" /></span></td><td class="icePnlGrdCol1 dataListPaginatorClassCol1" id="mainform:j_id1248-0-2"><span class="iceOutTxt dataListCurrentPage" id="mainform:j_id1253">0</span></td></tr></tbody></table>]]></content></update><update address="errorPageLink" tag="a"><attribute name="href"><![CDATA[/argus/error.seam?cid=14362238&amp;dbsid=6307399]]></attribute><attribute name="id"><![CDATA[errorPageLink]]></attribute><content><![CDATA[Отчет об ошибке]]></content></update><update address="TCfkqn0OYY6MKJ-cF4gZvQ:5:dynamic-code" tag="script"><attribute name="id"><![CDATA[TCfkqn0OYY6MKJ-cF4gZvQ:5:dynamic-code]]></attribute><attribute name="type"><![CDATA[text/javascript]]></attribute><content><![CDATA[new Ice.MenuBarKeyNavigator('j_id37:j_id41', false, false, true);new Ice.MenuBarKeyNavigator('mainform:filterColumnsMenu', false, false, true);new Ice.MenuBarKeyNavigator('mainform:sortingColumnsMenu', false, false, true);Sortable.create('mainform:sortingColumnsPositioned',{handle:'dsParamsDraggableElement',tag:'div',dropOnEmpty:true,constraint:'vertical',onUpdate:function(){var o = Sortable.options('mainform:sortingColumnsPositioned');var s = o.serializeValue;f = $('mainform:_idmainform:sortingColumnsPositionedcolOrder');f.value = s;},containment:false});new Ice.MenuBarKeyNavigator('mainform:groupingColumnsMenu', false, false, true);Sortable.create('mainform:groupingColumnsPositioned',{handle:'dsParamsDraggableElement',tag:'div',dropOnEmpty:true,constraint:'vertical',onUpdate:function(){var o = Sortable.options('mainform:groupingColumnsPositioned');var s = o.serializeValue;f = $('mainform:_idmainform:groupingColumnsPositionedcolOrder');f.value = s;},containment:false});Ice.modal.stop('j_id501:exportDialog');//-1252711350]]></content></update></updates>
```

Comment: Возможно, там происходит AJAX запрос, а результат вставляется в код страницы на лету. Нужно посмотреть, идёт ли куда-то запрос, когда нажимается кнопка. Если это AJAX, то вам придётся повторять это действие из приложения вручную.

Comment: @LEQADA дописал запрос, но чет все равно ничего не могу понять

Comment: А что там в Responce возвращается?

Comment: @LEQADA дописал. Оно?

Comment: `JSOUP` не выполняет `JavaScript`, при помощи которого показывается ваша табличка. У вас несколько вариантов: загружать страницу в `WebView`, программно нажимать на кнопку, и потом уже доставать `HTML` из него, и загружать в `JSOUP`, или же посмотреть сниффером, какие запросы куда отправляются из этой таблички, и отправлять их, не показывая ее.

Comment: @metalurgus так в прошлом моем вопросе Вы мне помогли с тем, как спарсить эту страничку. Сначала webview потом jsoup. Тут дело в том, что в и браузере на компе после нажатия кнопки в исходном коде нужные элементы не отображаются, и я не пойму как до них добраться

Comment: Вы хотя бы ссылку дайте

Comment: @metalurgus да блин если б можно было. сайт корпоративный, сразу логин/пароль запрашивает. служба безопасности не дремлет

Comment: тогда остается только отследить запросы, и отправлять такие же.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33400/discussion-between-alex-and-metalurgus).

Comment: @metalurgus это та Form Data которая отображена в посте?

Comment: Был у меня такой вопрос уже когда-то)

Comment: Нужно использовать headless browser, но это тот еще гемор